# websockets connection error (socket.io...?)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sockets, websocket, video-streaming

**i am clicking on call button once it does nothing when i click call buton twice only then only it establish connection**

***Frontend Code***

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

import peerconnection from '../PeerService';
import { useSocket } from '../context/socketContext';

function Videop2p() {
  
  const [remoteid, setRemoteId] = useState();
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
  const remoteVideoRef = useRef();
  const myVideoRef = useRef();
  const socket = useSocket();
  const handleICECandidate = async (event) => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      socket.emit('ice-candidate', { to: remoteid, candidate: event.candidate });
    }
    
  };

  const handleCall = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
      stream.getTracks().forEach((track) =>  peerconnection.peer.addTrack(track, stream));

      // if(!peerconnection.peer.answer)
      // {
      //   peerconnection.peer
      // }
      
      
      const offer = await peerconnection.peer.createOffer();
      peerconnection.peer.setLocalDescription(offer);

      socket.emit('call', { to: remoteid, offer });
      console.log('handling call');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error handling call:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    
    let stream;
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((s) => {
        myVideoRef.current.srcObject = s;
        stream = s; // Store the stream for cleanup
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error accessing media devices:', error));

    // Cleanup function for unmounting or changing dependencies
    return () => {
      if (stream) {
        stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      }
    };
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once on mount

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleIncomingCall = async ({ from, offer }) => {
      setRemoteId(from);
      console.log('incoming call');

      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
      stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => peerconnection.peer.addTrack(track, stream));

      // Ensure that the remote description is set before adding ICE candidates
      peerconnection.peer.setRemoteDescription(offer);
       
      const answer = await peerconnection.peer.createAnswer();
      peerconnection.peer.setLocalDescription(answer);

      socket.emit('call-accepted', { to: remoteid, answer });
    };

    socket.on('user-joined', ({ from, name }) => {
      setRemoteId(from);
      console.log(from);
    });

    socket.on('incomming-call', handleIncomingCall);

    socket.on('answer', async ({ from, answer }) => {
      // Ensure that the remote description is set before adding ICE candidates
      await peerconnection.peer.setRemoteDescription(answer);
      peerconnection.peer.onicecandidate = handleICECandidate;
      

    });

    socket.on('ice-candidate', async ({ from,candidate }) => {
      // Ensure that the remote description is set before adding ICE candidates
      
        try {
          peerconnection.peer.addIceCandidate(candidate);
          setConnected((prev) => !prev);
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error is',error);
        }
      
    });

    



    
    
    // Cleanup function for unmounting or changing dependencies
    return () => {
      socket.off('user-joined');
      socket.off('incomming-call', handleIncomingCall);
      socket.off('answer');
      socket.off('ice-candidate');
      // peerconnection.peer.ontrack = null;
      // peerconnection.peer.onicecandidate = null;
      // peerconnection.peer.onconnectionstatechange = null;
    };
  }); // Dependencies that trigger this effect

  useEffect(()=>{
    peerconnection.peer.ontrack = (event) => {
      remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = event.streams[0];
    };
    

    peerconnection.peer.onconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
      if (peerconnection.peer.connectionState === 'connected') {
        console.log('connection establish');
      }
    };
  },[connected]);

  

  

  return (
    <div>
      Your video
      <video ref={myVideoRef} playsInline autoPlay />
      {remoteid ? (
        <>
          <video ref={remoteVideoRef} playsInline autoPlay />
          <button onClick={handleCall}>Call</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>No one in this room</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Videop2p;
```

***backend code***

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import { createServer } from 'http';  // Updated import
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const Users = [];

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);  // Updated server creation
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  },
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`user connected ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on('create-room', ({ name, roomid }) => {
    socket.join(roomid);
    
  });

  socket.on('join-room',({name,roomid}) => {
    // io.to(roomid).emit('user-joined',{from : socket.id, name:name})
    io.to(roomid).emit('user-joined', { from: socket.id, roomid: roomid });
    socket.join(roomid);
    
  })

  socket.on('call',({to,offer})=>{
        io.to(to).emit('incomming-call',{from : socket.id, offer});
  })

  socket.on('call-accepted',({to,answer})=>{
    io.to(to).emit('answer',{from : socket.id,answer});
  })

  socket.on('ice-candidate', ({ to, candidate }) => {
    io.to(to).emit('ice-candidate', { from: socket.id, candidate });
  });
 

  // Add more socket events as needed

  // Example: handle disconnect event
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`user disconnected ${socket.id}`);
    // Perform any cleanup or necessary actions on user disconnect
  });
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('server started on 5000');
});
```

***peerservice.js code***

```
class peerservice {
    static iceConfiguration = {
        iceServers: [
            { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
            { urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
            { urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
            { urls: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
            { urls: 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' },
        ],
    };

    constructor() {
        this.peer = new RTCPeerConnection(peerservice.iceConfiguration);
    }
}

export default new peerservice();
```

i want that on just single click call connection should get establish please help i think there is some problem with flow or ussage of use effect i am not sure about it but i think please if ou can find a bug or can fix it it will be great help